# How to use Visual Studio for diagram-first database design and generation if I don't want to use Entity framework?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, database-design

I just want to "draw" a database structure and generate an SQL script to create all the tables and keys (the way I used to do with ERWin and MySQL Workbench). And I don't want any ORM classes to be created (as I am going to do all the database querying manually). How to achieve this?

Comment: If you're OK with buying, I would recommend Enterprise Architect from Sparx. Can generate SQL from a diagram and also reverse engineer existing schema into a diagram, among hundreds of other things that make it totally worth the $200 for the Professional edition.

Answer (score 0):

Not being familiar with the mentioned tools, are you looking for [Database Diagrams](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188251.aspx)